# copy a character array from a pointer variable

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
VOID change(CHAR *TP, CHAR *FR, BOOL Vw)
{
CHAR *User, *NU, *CU = NULL, *Ref = NULL;
int Loop = 0;
<Some lines of code>

   if(Loop == 0)
      memcpy(Ref, FR, strlen(FR)+1);

   CU = NU;
   Loop++;
}
   if(CU)
   free(CU);

}// end of function
```

Ok so as you can see... the **FR** is a pointer to a character array.. and each time it sends the memory location..
and I  have to copy it to **Ref**..

But all these are pointer variables..

What I need to do is.. I need to make a character array Lets say 
**AZ** and it will contain,

**AZ** = the character array **FR** points to + "/abcd" +

then i will do a **memcpy** of **AZ** to **Ref**...

My problem is the **FR** variable is a pointer and I cant understand how to put that into a character array and then add characters to the final array..

Comment: Are these variables anonymized? What is the purpose of this function? Can't you use the C++ standard library? I'm happy that I don't need to maintain that code.

Comment: Are you sure this is C++ and not C?  If you wanted to do real C++ you wouldn't be manipulating `char` pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `Ref` has enough memory allocated to hold the strings that you want to concatenate.

Then you can use the `strcpy()` function to copy the first string to `Ref`, and `strcat()` to concatenate additional strings. For example:

```
strcpy(Ref, AZ);
strcat(Ref, "/abcd");
strcat(Ref, more_stuff);
```